# How Do I Create a Facebook App That I Can Add to a Page and Only Likers Will See

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml

I have a Facebook page that I created and I want to create a contest app that only likers can see. I was able to do this in the past using FBML but ever since Facebook has stopped using FBML, I can't seem to do this with IFrame apps. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we can give you guidance. You can either develop the whole thing yourself or use a pre-built product like the one provided by [Strutta](http://www.strutta.com) (*not free!*).

Now how to develop a contest system is up to you, but how to make it available only to fans is easy. You just need to read the `signed_request`, look for the [`page`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) parameter and check if the `liked` field is set or not. This is [how to do it](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/) in PHP:

```
<?php
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
    echo "You are not a fan!";
} else {
    echo "Welcome back fan!";
}
?>
```

You may need to take a look at the [Promotions Guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php).